# Client Ionic (ng-socket-io) e servidor SpringBoot com SockJs

Tags: ionic, websocket

Tenho um aplicativo feito com **Ionic 3** que usa como client de WebSocket o **ng-socket-io** e tenho um servidor WebSocket que foi implementado com **SockJs** no Spring Boot.

Pelo que li, Spring Boot não consegue trabalhar com Websocket.io.

Preciso implementar um client com **SockJs** ou um back-end com websocket.io (Spring Boot).

Detalhe que o Back-End tem que ser em Spring Boot.

Alguém me sugere algo? Valeu!

Comment: Acredito ter achado a solução. Implementei no Spring Boot um Websocket usando netty-socketio. Depois posto aqui link do GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi implementar no Spring Boot um Websocket usando netty-socketio.